# Advanced book for English Phonology?

Tags: phonology

pals.

Does anyone know any advanced book(s) in Phonology of English and could give me a title/the titles, please?
I am studying English Philology (so English is my 2nd language) and we've just finished April McMahon's 'An Introduction to English Philology' and I want some more!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Philology or phonology? They're very different things.

Comment: English Philology is the name of my studies consisting of different courses like Linguistics, Phonology, Phonetics, Literature etc. So phonology is a separate course.

Comment: Ah, I see; you're looking to go from a general-purpose book and course that covered only the basics of phonology among many topics, to a book specifically on phonology that covers things in greater depth? That makes a lot more sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics! This question is better suited on Language Learning.SE.

Comment: McMahon's *An Introduction to English Philology* does have a "Recommendations for reading" section at the end of each chapter, so I suggest you start looking for a book that suits your interest and comprehension from there.

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend [The Sound Pattern of English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sound_Pattern_of_English), with the cautionary note that it is advanced in the sense that it should be read critically, without necessarily accepting the theory that it advances.

Comment: Oooh it's by Chomsky, very nice. Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you tell me how complete of an english phonology this work is?

Comment: SPE is mostly about general issues in phonological theory and how those work out for English morphophonemics.  English dialects and casual speech phonology are not covered.

Comment: Can you recommend a book that is dedicated to English phonology then?

Comment: I thought I did that already.

Comment: Oh, okay. Since you said it dealt with general phonological issues I presumed it was more like a debate, telling the ideas of other theorists and affirming the ones presented by the authors in a not very language-specific way.